# Why doesn't the example of express-formidable work on my code?

Tags: node.js, express, formidable

I'm trying to use this module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable

but when I launch my app terminal returns:

```
app.use(formidable());
        ^

TypeError: formidable is not a function
```

why?

Comment: Can you show some code how you require the module?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `formidable` to your app after you are done installing it with `npm i -S express-formidable`

Copy paste from the readme,

```
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require('express-formidable');

var app = express();

app.use(formidable());
```

Comment: Really I added firstly formidable and then express-formidable :-) how ever I resolved reinstall all modules that I use on my app ... perhaps some incompatibility between old nodue_modules folder and the new one!

Answer (score 1):

I resolve reinstalling the moduels that I have on my app.
I did also a clean on my package.json so now works correctly!

Here its are the two parts of my package that I change:

old:

  `"dependencies": {
    "base64url": "^2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "1.9.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "connect": "^3.5.0",
    "connect-redis": "^3.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "4.10.1",
    "express-formidable": "^0.1.3",
    "express-session": "^1.14.1",
    "formidable": "^1.0.17",
    "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
    "helmet": "^2.1.3",
    "jwt-simple": "~0.5.0",
    "morgan": "1.5.0",
    "multer": "^1.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.9.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "router": "^1.1.4",
    "time": "^0.11.4"
  }`

and the new one:

`"dependencies": {
    "base64url": "^2.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "compression": "^1.6.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-formidable": "^1.0.0",
    "express-session": "^1.14.1",
    "fs-extra": "^0.30.0",
    "helmet": "^2.3.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "mysql": "^2.11.1"
  }`

perhaps there is some incompatibility between the modules ...